# Are MOOCs a good way to show grad schools that I've gained proficiency in a field which is not my major?

Tags: graduate-admissions, changing-fields, mooc, biotechnology

I'm an undergraduate computer science major with a specialization in networks and communication looking at a masters in molecular genetics. In addition to a GRE biochemistry and molecular biology subject test score, I'm interested in MOOCs to enhance my resume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with MOOCs, all of which make them a poor substitute for actual classes for admissions.

- Poor penetration. There is more widespread knowledge of them than a couple years ago, but they are still fairly unknown. Chances are high at at least someone reading your application won't know about or understand them.
- No grades. Few MOOCs offer anything more than a certificate of completion, and many don't even offer that. Even if they offered grades, verification of identity is a problem.
- Wildly varying quality. College classes are generally of a certain quality/difficulty, and knowledge of the quality/difficulty levels for certain field-specific classes across schools is something that application committees will use to judge candidates against each other. MOOCs are much more of an unknown.

Answer (score 0):

No, because many people still do not know what MOOCs are (though they have been in the press a lot).  Those who know what they are may not be sure if they are effective.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say as it differs from university to university. But an MOOC course cannot act as a substitute to an actual course in a college because the depth of the subject is simply not enough in an MOOC. Hope this helps.